# How can I restrict end user permission to read only in my zeppelin charts?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

When I want to share my generated charts to end user as a HTTP link.
How can I share to him and How can I restrict to my end user can only read only this charts i.e.
Suppose using shared link option in zepplin settings.

my shared link : http://localhost:8096/#/notebook/2BEGBD5NW/paragraph/20160226-011205_1827442832?asIframe

I shared to my end user.

suppose my end user editing the url  http://localhost:8096/#/notebook/

He is able to see all my note books. but I want restrict access  to only below mentioned url.

http://localhost:8096/#/notebook/2BEGBD5NW/paragraph/20160226-011205_1827442832?asIframe

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The question is old but I am currently investigating the same topic.

one can filter urls in shiro.ini

[urls]

/api/notebook/2BEGBD5NW/paragraph/20160226-011205_1827442832 = anon //oder der user der es lesen können soll
/** = authc, roles[internalUser]

It matches first url starting from the top and uses those filters.
While that would restrict everything except the one notebook, websockets are still there and cannot be filtered that same way.

The permissions per notebook/interpreter are independent of shiro.ini and have their effect regardless.

Comment: Above solution only allows the API access, but page url which is (/#/notebook/....) does not work. Have you tried providing access to generated URL?